# Image Control disapear after it's dragged in Design

Tags: wpf, image

I'm a WPF newbie and, unlike WinForms, I have a hard time to setup things in the design window.

My first obstacle is the Image control. After I drag it in the Design window it disappears and there's no way for me to edit its properties (like with the button control for example). The only way to make changes is via the XAML code which isn't very visual and intuitive.

Is there a way to keep editing the Image control in design mode? (example, move it around, select it to view its property panel, etc.)

Comment: Take a look at the document outline to find the Image control; highlight it and then edit the properties in the properties panel.

Comment: designer is not the best way to create wpf UI, if you want to learn wpf, start learning xaml.

Comment: I wondering, why Microsoft bothered to implement a designer if UI can hardly be edited from it? Besides, is Expression Blend absolutely necessary to make UI in an intuitive way?

Comment: The Visual Studio designer does have limitations, but once you get a hang of some of the idiosyncrasies, the designer can be useful. Blend is a fantastic product and you can learn a tremendous amount about WPF layouts once you understand the fundamentals of using Blend. Personally, I switch between the two quite often and will spend a fair amount of time in XAML more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is give the image control a fixed height and width and it should stay in the designer.

Comment: In the properties I've set "width" and "height" to 200, it doesn't change anything. Also, is there a way to make the image start with a background color just like PictureBox? Let's suppose I want the image background black and make it visible the design?

Comment: That's weird, i created a test project in visual studio 2010 and just dragged an image onto the design surface and the control's border is easily visible.  In the xaml or through the properties window just set the source property to an image on you machine, just use an absolute path. Could you please post the xaml.  That would help figure out what is going on. alos what version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score -1):

The best thing about the XAML is which separated from code for better re usability like asp.net. It's best you to learn different layouts such as grid, wrappanel, stackpanel etc. Then, you will feel the power of xaml. Else, you can choose the XAML building tools.

[Link to refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx)

Comment: I've read bout the different layouts, and actually my image is dragged in the default grid. From this point I still would like to make further changes to my image control from the design mode.

Comment: OK.Also check your control has appropriate positioning. And right click of the control and choose properties to modify through UI. will this helpful mark as answer and let u know have more queries.